# send emails from a form in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am fairly new to VBA and I am trying to create some code which will email the details from a form in MS Access

The form is called customer and the fields are ID, Name, and email.

I have used the code below taken from another site and I keep getting errors

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command7_Click()

Dim ID, name, email
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem


ID = Customer!ID
name = Customer!name
email = Customer!email

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .To = email
    .Subject = ID
    .send
End With

Set objEmail = Nothing
objOutlook.Quit


End Sub
```

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you, if you'd told us, what errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an error unless you set a reference to the Outlook library.

Try this instead, it uses late binding to the Outlook object.

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()

Dim ID, name, email 'You should probably make these something other than variants
Dim objOutlook    As Object
Dim objEmail      As Object


ID = Customer!ID
name = Customer!name
email = Customer!email

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0) '0 is the enum for olMailItem

With objEmail
    .To = email
    .Subject = ID
    .send
End With

Set objEmail = Nothing
set objOutlook = nothing

End Sub
```